# Python unable to assign a value in a class

Tags: class, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

I am not able to pass/assign a value in a class.
This is my class definition and basically I want to change the colour based on tod(time of day) .

```
class Meter(tk.Canvas):

    def __init__(self,master,*args,**kwargs):
        super(Meter,self).__init__(master,*args,**kwargs)

        self.tod=tod
        self.layoutparams(tod)
        self.graphics()
        self.createhand()
        self.setrange()


    def layoutparams(self,tod):
        # set parameters that control the layout
        height = int(self['height'])
        width = int(self['width'])


        # find a square that fits in the window
        if(height*2 > width):
            side = width
        else:
            side = height*2

        # set axis for hand
        self.centrex = side/2
        self.centrey = side/2

        # standard with of lines
        self.linewidth = 2

        # outer radius for dial
        self.radius = int(0.40*float(side))

        # set width of bezel
        self.bezel = self.radius/15
        self.bezelcolour1 = 'green'
here is where i change the colour
        if (tod=='day'):
            self.bezelcolour2 = 'black'
        else:
            self.bezelcolour2 = 'white'
        self.bezelcolour3 = 'red'

        # set lengths of ticks and hand
        self.majortick = self.radius/8
        self.minortick = self.majortick/2
```

And here is how I do the instance

```
    w=Meter(self,height = 400,width = 400)
    w.tod='day'
```

I am getting this error

```
line 27, in __init__
    self.tod=tod
NameError: name 'tod' is not defined
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exactly what the error is telling you. You're assigning the value of `tod` to `self.tod`, but you don't have a variable named `tod`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write:

```
w=Meter(self,height = 400,width = 400, tod='day')
```

and it would be better to write:

```
if (self.tod=='day'):
```

You should probably also add a function `changeTod`.